# R.java error .. gen folder file is not generating

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

R.java error .. gen folder file is not generating in android environment.

I tried clean and build.
Android target version and everything goes fine.
Recreated the project.
Restarted eclipse .
But, still its in R.java error.

How to solve it.. please give me an answer.

I am using UBUNTU

Comment: see : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-comprehensive-troubleshooting-guide-for-androids-r-cannot-be-resolved-error/

Answer (score 0):

This question tends to be asked a lot. Take a look at the top answer here:

[R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error?answertab=votes#tab-top)